# how call non static method in android

Tags: methods, non-static

How to call non static method in android ?? I have try all way I can, but nothing. i have try this code in java and success for running, but why in android always error.
Here is the code of main activity.

```
public class Main extends Activity{
private Coba mstatus;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) 
        {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.download:
                    ....

                    break;

        case R.id.resume:
            mstatus.resume();
            break;

        }
}
```

This is the second class.

```
public abstract class Coba implements runnable{

....

public void resume(){
download();
}
public void download() {
mThread = new Thread(this);
mThread.start();
}    

}
```

I want to call `resume()` method. In my source code nothing warning and error but when I try to call this method it's always force close. Is there another way to call non static method from another class ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather a java issue than an Android one:

First Coba is abstract so you should use a non abstract class, let's call this class CobaImpl 
or make Coba a non abstract class (you choose).

Second you should create an instance of the class to use a non static method (eg mstatus = new CobaImpl(...) elsewhere you can use only static method.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I can not change the abstract because it is used to process runnable and cannot use static method. sorry for not completed question. i will edit that question. hope you can help me.